# A mathematician who wants to learn particle physics

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, education

I am a grad student in pure math, wrapping up a thesis in Lie theory. After years of talking to mathematicians and physicists, I've decided that it's time to get some formal training in physics, particularly in particle physics.

I have no formal training in physics. We're talking only a childish understanding of basic mechanics and bits and pieces of relativity and CFT, I have seen Maxwell's equations once or twice, etc. But I know Riemannian/pseudo-Riemannian geometry, the representation theory of compact and semi-simple Lie groups, some PDE, and so forth. So hopefully the math shouldn't be an issue.

With so little physics training (and hence little physical intuition!) what kind of books do you guys recommend?

Comment: I just find this book "Classical and quantum mechanics
via Lie algebras" by Arnold Neumaier & Dennis Westra. I suggest to you to check it. Maybe, just maybe could be helpful for you. Also you could check the book "Introduction
to Groups, Invariants and Particles" by Frank W. K. Firk.

Comment: Also check the book "Geometric Algebra For Physicists" by Chris J. L. Doran & Anthony N. Lasenby, it has a lot of applications in classical mechanics, special relativity, electrodynamics, quantum theory, gauge theory and gravitation.

Comment: There's a great book on classical mechanics by Spivak that came out recently "Physics for Mathematicians: Mechanics I." I'd consider trying to learn some basic electrodynamics an particle physics from something like "Introduction to Elementary Particles" by Griffiths.  There are also a ton of great online lectures like http://www.pa.ucla.edu/content/eric-dhoker-lecture-notes, and http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html .  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys. I had a list of a ton of possible books to read, and *none* of the sources recommended here were on it :-)